# Power law from csv data (Python)

Tags: python, plot, power-law

How can I fit a power law function in a plot and extract the alpha and sigma values using python?

The closest I found was this, posted by the user [AcCap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640496/python-plot-and-powerlaw-fit) :

```
import powerlaw
d=[6, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3,2,  3, 3, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
fit = powerlaw.Fit(numpy.array(d)+1,xmin=1,discrete=True)
fit.power_law.plot_pdf( color= 'b',linestyle='--',label='fit ccdf')
fit.plot_pdf( color= 'b')

print('alpha= ',fit.power_law.alpha,'  sigma= ',fit.power_law.sigma)
```

But I don't know how can I go from it to using a csv data, where column A is axis X and column B is axis Y..